# Посоветуйте ресурс

Tags: java, android

Мое приложение рассчитано на устройства не ниже Android 5.0 и я вот о чем подумал, мне нужно создать файл ресурсов `dimens` для различных плотностей экранов.

Существует 6 разных классификаций плотностей но возможно есть какой нибудь ресурс на котором описывают какие плотности экранов есть у девайсов версии 5.0 и выше, чтоб не создавать куча папок... Наверняка как минимум `ldpi` не используют устройства которые получили 5.0

Или это не правильный подход и нужно создать все 6 папок для всех плотностей и протестировать их?

Кстати для информации приложение рассчитано только на телефоны и только на портретную ориентацию...

Спасибо за совет!

Comment: А зачем делать разные дименшены для разных плотностей? Просто указывайте размеры в dp и всё.